# ruby return section of directory name

Tags: ruby

I have a directory, which contains a series of folders, which are of the pattern `YYYY-MM-DD_NUMBER` .  If I am navigating through one of these folders using Dir, how can I return part of the folder name that contains `YYYY-MM-DD` ?

For example, `2013-05-23_160332` would be a name of a folder.  And it would be apart of a larger directory, called `main_dir`.  I use Dir to get access to some file names and store them into an array, like so:

```
array = Dir["/main_dir/**/data/*.csv"]
```

I then iterate through the array and print the files.  How can I also return/print the part of the title directory that I am currently accessing with each iteration (again, in the form of `YYYY-MM-DD`)?

Comment: So you only want to see the dates from the folder names?

Comment: Sounds like a job for `grep` or `scan`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might do something like this.

```
re = Regexp.new('\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}')

array.each do |folder|
  puts folder[re]
  # folder.each or other processing ...
end
```

Comment: Incredible!  Thank you very much.